# Best way to convert '04-17-2013' to '2013-04-17' in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I had the following:

```
$order_date = '04-17-2013';
echo $order_date . "\n";

$order_date = date_create($order_date);
$order_date = date_format($order_date, 'Y-m-d');

echo $order_date;
```

The output is:

```
before = 04-17-2013
after  =
```

I thought I had that working but must have been mistaken, since it's not working now!

**UPDATED WITH SOLUTION USED**

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $order_date);
$new_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. I think the $order_date you pass to the function is malformed which is why it is not working.

Comment: I just added the date that's being passed to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<s>$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($order_date));</s>

This won't work. Dates in the `m/d/y` or `d-m-y` formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed. [(source)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$new_date = date_create_from_format('m-d-Y', $order_date);
```

or

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $order_date);
$new_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VlvcNr)

or in PHP 5.5+

```
$new_date = (DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $order_date))->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6

Comment: Oh, duh. I typo'd. Sorry. Try it now with the change (Form -> From)

Comment: I'm new to that double colon method. Is there anything I need to know about using that? I just did a straight substitution for my code, swapping it over entirely as it is. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. And `::` is the [Scope Resolution Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php). You don't need to know much about it to use it here. When you get into advanced PHP then understanding it well is important.

Answer (score 2):

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($order_date));
```

Comment: Ohhh. Looks like he edited the question. That's why. The way he originally had it, it would have.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a simple [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$order_date = '04-17-2013';
list($m, $d, $y) = explode('-', $order_date);
$order_date = $y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d;
echo $order_date; // 2013-04-17
```

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/LGRNgn).

---

A one liner ?

```
$order_date = '04-17-2013';
$order_date = preg_replace('/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/', '$3-$1-$2', $order_date);
echo $order_date; // 2013-04-17
```

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tssnRp).

Comment: Thanks. I did consider that, but I think it's messy if there is already a function designed to do the same thing in one line.

Comment: @PeterSnow You want a one liner ? You got it :p